# Catch the iPhone's autocorrect suggestion

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, autocorrect

I want to catch the iPhone's autocorrect suggestion and insert it into a new array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can get suggestions for words using the `UITextChecker` class : https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html